# Incorrect bar graph formatting in TeX

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, axis

For some reason, two very simple Bar graphs look very different after compiling in tex. More precisely, on the right graph there is a distance from the columns to the lower border of the square. In the left graph, the columns are adjacent to the lower border of the square. I would like to change the left figure, to have the distance between the bottom of the square and the blue columns on the left chart, as it is implemented on the right. Do you know how to change the code of the left chart?

[image: Picture]

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.49\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.75,-1)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5,6},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical}
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(1, 179) (2, 122) (3, 79) (4, 59) (5, 49) (6, 205) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.49\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.75,-1)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5,6},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical}
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(1, 125) (2, 106) (3, 27) (4, 49) (5, 12) (6, 5) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Add option
`
ytick distance=50,
ymin=0,`
to both plots.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={group size=2 by 1},
    ybar,
    symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5,6},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical}
                    ]
\nextgroupplot[enlarge y limits=0.4, ymax=250]
\addplot coordinates {(1, 179) (2, 122) (3, 79) (4, 59) (5, 49) (6, 205) };
%
\nextgroupplot[enlarge y limits=0.166,ymax=150]%0.166=250/150
\addplot coordinates {(1, 125) (2, 106) (3, 27) (4, 49) (5, 12) (6, 5) };
\end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- As you can see, in MWE is used `groupplot` where are in  each group defined `ymax` and `enlarge y limits`. Later are in ration of used `ymax`.
- In above MWE are not defined `legen` styles, since in your MWE legends are not used.